# Force fail a function and continue after x amount of time

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function which is in a for loop. The function takes a string as an argument, and then using some regex, it returns something I need from the string.

Example:

```
const strings = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3', ...]

for (let i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
   extractString(strings[i])
}

function extractString(string) {
   return string.match(...)
}
```

Now the problem is sometimes that the string is very big, and the function just hangs there and the application becomes unresponsive.
I've tried using a try catch but that didn't do anything.

How would I go about making it so, if after X amount of seconds the function did not return the match, I just fail it and force continue the for loop? Is that possible? Is there a better solution in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: No, that's not possible. You can't kill a function from outside. You have to implement a logic inside the function.

Comment: have you tried putting an if statement inside the function like `if(string.length>reasonableLength){return false}`?

Comment: What do you mean by fail ? Should it raise an error or return something or ignore the string ?
Also, did you tried with async function ?

Comment: Modern computers are insanely fast. Thus, I reckon the real problem lies inside `extractString`: forget about this present question and post a new one, sharing that function, so people can analyse its efficiency, if it's bad like O(n^2) or O(2^n) or even terrible like O(n!). Depending on the regex you're using it can be greatly improved.

Comment: You tagged the question with Node.js. You can start a new process for each function call and kill the process after some time. Creating and killing processes has some overhead.

Comment: the function might get called a lot, how about this.. you have a child process that you spawn at the beginning of your program dedicated to this, or in my previous comment _just ignore strings that are too long_

Comment: @jabaa yes, it's being run on node.js. Do you have some docs/examples or something that I can read into that?

Comment: [Kill a process](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processkillpid-signal) or [kill a subprocess](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#subprocesskillsignal) and [create a child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#asynchronous-process-creation)

Comment: @TheBombSquad that's a solution yeah, but I would rather go this way if possible.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado here is the regex const matches = string.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi)
It just finds emails in a huge string.